# Print index table with prawn ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, parameters, prawn

I'm having trouble trying to print the array that a search produces in the index of my app. Here is my code:

**appointments controller (index action):**

```
def index
  @appointments = Appointment.search(params[:search])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = AppointmentsPdf.new(@appointments)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "citas_del_dia",
                                type: "application/pdf",
                         disposition: "inline"
    end
  end
end
```

**index view:**

```
<%= form_tag @appointments_path, :method => 'get', :id => "appointments_search" do %>
    <%= date_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "search date", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<div><%= render 'appointments' %></div>


<%= link_to "Print appointments of the day",appointments_path(@appointments, :format => 'pdf'), target: "_blank" %>
```

**and my prawn pdf class:**

```
class AppointmentsPdf < Prawn::Document
    def initialize(appointments)
        super(top_margin: 30, :page_layout => :landscape)
        @appointments = appointments
        #some code to fill the pdf.
```

Now the problem is that it renders the index fine when I search for an specific date but when I want to print that page to pdf it prints nothing as if the search where null which is not. I think I have to pass the search like a parameter to the prawn class but I don't know where or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by passing the search param through the link to method like so:

```
<%= link_to "appointments of the day", citas_del_dia_appointments_path(@appointments, :format => 'pdf', :search => params[:search]), target: "_blank" %>
```

now it works like a charm